# Why does this python script not run when executed from my batch file?

Tags: python, windows, batch-file

I have a batch file set up to run a ghostscript which creates a .pdf output, which I then want to use in a subsequent python script. The batch file itself runs without issue and looks like this:

```
"%PROGRAMFILES%\gs\gs9.54.0\bin\gswin64c.exe" -dBATCH -dSAFER -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress -dAutoRotatePages=/PageByPage -r600 -sOutputFile=%~dp0\%result%.pdf -
^&
"%~dp0\test.py" %result%.pdf
```

The batch file log shows that it executes all commands. Furthermore, a dummy python script that does nothing but log that it ran also works perfectly. However, when I substitute the dummy for the script I want to use, the file does not do what it should, despite running perfectly when run on its own from the console. The python script looks like this:

```
import os
import sys
from rmapy.document import ZipDocument
from rmapy.api import Client
        
# sets up the current directory to be the same as the .py file
os.chdir(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

# sets up the remarkable api
rm=Client()
rm.renew_token()

# finds the pdf
for arg in sys.argv[1:]:
    print(arg)
    rawDocument = ZipDocument(doc=arg)
    rawDocument.metadata["VissibleName"]
    rm.upload(rawDocument)
```

I highly appreciate any help you are able to offer. I suspect there is something in the .py file that produces an error when called through the batch file, but I can't figure out what.

Comment: Perhaps `"VissibleName"` -> `"VisibleName"` in the second to last line of the script? That might give a KeyError

Comment: @asdf101 Nope, that's directly related to the rmapy package and is for some reason written that way.

Comment: The `print everything you can` debugging method might help, perhaps rmapy raises an exception or the [1:]  slice has some problems. Add some print statements that let you identify until where the code runs and run again

Comment: Another option is to use one or more `try-except` blocks to catch potential exceptions